# CKEditor 3.6.4 and RequiredField in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor, required-field

I have used CKEditor 3.6.4 in my asp.net form with other `RequiredField` fields. While submitting form  the `RequiredField` validator control is not working for first time. CKEditor validation is false. Please help me for validating fields at first time also.

Thanks

Comment: "flashed" - what does this mean?

Comment: Hmm. Could you show us the relevant parts your view code; at least where you create the editor and where you do the submit? Sounds like an updateElement issue.